# How to Iterate though images with different extensions in a folder using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate through all images with different extensions from a folder but unfortunately it only iterates on the first one ('.jpg'), why ? 
yes I have images with all other extensions too.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    var img = 0;
    var slides = new Array();
    var fileextension = [".jpg" || ".jpeg" || ".bmp" || ".gif" || ".png"];

    while (img < 7)
    {
        img++;
        var src = 'images/' + img + fileextension;
        slides.push(src);
    }

    var index = 0, timer = 0;
    showNextSlide();
    timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 10000);

    function showNextSlide()
    {
        if (index >= slides.length)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('img1').src = slides[index++];
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all images with all file extensions, you need to loop over the file extensions too. Change your `var fileextension=[];` to a real array:

```
var fileextension = [".jpg",".jpeg",".bmp",".gif",".png"];

while (img < 7)
{
    img++;
    fileextension.forEach(function(ext){
        var src = 'images/' + img + ext;
        //see the result in the console:
        console.log(src, ext)
        slides.push(src);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you had in mind is to try all possible extensions for each image and rely on one of them being available.

As @Maciej noted, the code posted doesn't achieve this logic, but this can be done using a somewhat different logic and the onLoad event.

However, as the code is running in the browser, doing it this way would be highly expensive and inefficient because you would be making 5x7 HTTP requests in order to get 7 images eventually.

I would recommend one of these options:

1. If possible, use a standard format and extension for all the images.
   You can also optimize the images when converting them to the standard format as an added benefit.
2. If you have server-side logic, make an AJAX call to get a list of available images from the server

Comment: Thanks Giladd I think I might have to go through the Ajax route.

Answer (score 1):

You define `var fileextension = [".jpg" || ".jpeg" || ".bmp" || ".gif" || ".png"];` with using `||` (OR) operator. Therefore initialisation of your database is equivalent to
`var fileextension = [".jpg"];` This is because `||` returns first value which converted to Boolean is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what would you suggest ? I have tried comma without any joy.